# Error passing parameters and retrieving key value result set

Tags: mybatis

I'm having problems understanding how MyBatis maps parameters passed in, and then marshalling the results back to the caller.  I'd like to pass a POJO in, use properties set in there as part of the query and pass the results back in a map form.

My Mapping file function (without using the parameters):

```
    <select id="getTotalUniqueUserDetails" 
            resultType="map" 
            parameterType="RequestFilter">
        select KEY,sum(SINGLE_VALUE) as TOTAL from (
            select schut.user_type_name as KEY, schuc.usage_count AS SINGLE_VALUE 
            from usage_count schuc
            left join users schu
            on schuc.user_key=schu.user_key
            left join user_types schut
            on schut.user_type_id=schu.user_type_id
         ) 
         GROUP by KEY;
    </select>
```

My Mapping file function (with the parameters)

```
    <select id="getTotalUniqueUserDetails" 
            resultType="map" 
            parameterType="RequestFilter">
        select KEY,sum(SINGLE_VALUE) as TOTAL from (
            select schut.user_type_name as KEY, schuc.usage_count AS SINGLE_VALUE 
            from usage_count schuc
            left join users schu
            on schuc.user_key=schu.user_key
            left join user_types schut
            on schut.user_type_id=schu.user_type_id
            where schuc.year_month between 
                       to_date('#{fromDate}','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                   and to_date('#{toDate}','yyyy-mm-dd')

         ) 
         GROUP by KEY;
    </select>
```

My mapper interface

```
    public interface TotalUniqueUsers {
        Object getTotalUniqueUserDetails(RequestFilter filter);

    }
```

```
public class RequestFilter {
    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;
   ... getters and setters for both above 
}
```

```
The code that calls the query:
```

```
SqlSession sqlSession = DBConnection.getInstance().getSqlSession();
System.out.println("@@@@"+filter.getFromDate());
System.out.println("@@@@"+filter.getToDate());
TotalUniqueUsers testMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(TotalUniqueUsers.class);
return testMapper.getTotalUniqueUserDetails(filter);
```

```
With no parameters used in mapping file I get this error:
```

```
## The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select KEY,sum(SINGLE_VALUE) as TOTAL from (             select schut.user_type_name as KEY, schuc.usage_count AS SINGLE_VALUE from              usage_count schuc             left join users schu             on schuc.user_key=schu.user_key             left join user_types schut             on schut.user_type_id=schu.user_type_id          )           GROUP by KEY;
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

```
With parameters referenced in mapping file I get this error:
```

```
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='fromDate', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

```
If you've read this much, thank you from the Woodsman.

In short, if I use the parameter passed in the object, it says it can't use a null value. If I don't then it gives me some other error.

The result set should be something like
KEY      TOTAL
GROUP1    33
GROUP2    55

I was hoping I could just let it stuff the result set into a map, with the keys being "GROUP1", "GROUP2", with their respective values.

Please tell me how to properly refer to the properties in the object in the map and how to marshall it back.  Should I use a custom object?
```

Comment: Two basic mistakes. You need to remove 1) the semicolon at the end of the statement and 2) single quotes surrounding parameter placeholders e.g. `'#{fromDate}'` to `#{fromDate}`. Then see what happens. :)

Comment: Thanks @ave That worked. I'd mark that as answered if I could.

Comment: Glad to know it worked! I posted the answer with brief explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove...

1. The semicolon at the end of the statement. Although not all drivers reject it, it is a common cause for ORA-00933 with Oracle's JDBC driver.
2. The single quotes surrounding the parameter placeholders e.g. `'#{toDate}'` to `#{toDate}`.
   With single quotes, the first argument of `to_date` function becomes a literal instead of a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` placeholder (e.g. `to_date('?', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` instead of `to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`). When MyBatis tries to call `PreparedStatement#setString(int parameterIndex, String parameterValue)`, there is no placeholder in the statement and the driver throws the exception.